# UITableView headerView scroll offset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

I'm facing a problem with `UITableView` and it's property `tableHeaderView`.

I want to have the `tableHeaderView` to behave like `UISearchBar`, i.e. the content offset should be  the of tableHeaderView.
Setting contentOffset, etc. didn't help when the table view wouldn't fill the view's frame.

Here's a screenshot of the current behavior:

[image: current behavior]
<sub>(source: [tubtub.de](http://tubtub.de/export/now.png))</sub>

And how I'd like it to have:

[image: desired behavior]
<sub>(source: [tubtub.de](http://tubtub.de/export/desired.png))</sub>

I'm inserting the `headerView` in `viewDidLoad` as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
}
```

Any help or hint is highly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I made it working by utilizing UIScrollViewDelegate and subclassing UITableView. Check it out on the [github repo](https://github.com/bhr/BHRSnappingTableView/) provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with implementing my own solution.

I utilize `UIScrollViewDelegate` and came up with a subclass of `UITableView` for calculating the `contentSize` dynamically.

Take a look at the github repo [here](https://github.com/bhr/BHRSnappingTableView/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use setContentOffset: by headerView height.
This contentOffset will only happen when you have enough number of data to be off by your headerView height. i.e) If tableView is not scrollable because you have only few data like one in your screenshot, the headerView is still visible. However if you have lots of number of data that can't not be displayed in the screen it will have contentOffset.

Try this with 20 rows. You will see what I mean.

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 44)];
```

With only 3 rows, this contentOffset won't work and it might be desired behavior in your case because you don't want to hide the searchBar when you have extra space to display.

Comment: I'd really like to have the contentOffset be applied always, no matter how much data the table displays. I might be trying to hack my way around…

Answer (score 0):

I would double check the frame for the table itself.  By setting the headerView's frame to start at 0,0, you are specifying that it should have its origin in the top left of the the view that is designated for the table.